# How do i extend the header div to fit a whole page?

Tags: html, dreamweaver, indentation

I realise this question has been asked many times but i am going crazy trying to figure it out.

I am quite new to html and want to built a static header (940px x 30px) containing our logo, navbar, and a few social networking icons.

What i'm struggling to do is make the header fit the entire page, it leaves part of my background on show on the left, top and right sides which is frustrating.

below is the code i have used.

HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<title>TWChome</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="headercontents">
        Hello
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS Code

```
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

body {
    background-image:url(../images/bg.jpg);
}

div#header {
    display:block;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    background-image:url(../images/bar.jpg);
}

div#headercontents {
    width:50%;
}
```

Comment: you seem to be doing a [fine job](http://jsfiddle.net/4KqQc/) keeping the header container fitting the document's width.

Comment: If you're refering to the margin and padding values, you can reset your CSS to clear values, as in http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: oh yeah, that's probably the *Normalize.css* speaking here.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
body{margin:0;padding:0}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is actualy not that hard:

```
#header {
 width: 940px;
 height: 30px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

First you set the dimensions you say you want it to have, and then you center it. Nothing more to it. Also I have no idea why you are setting the #header-contents to a width of 50%...

update for header with background image:

```
 #header {
   height: 30px;
   background: url(../images/bar.jpg) no-repeat center center; /* for a single image with height of approx 30px */
   background: url(../images/bar.jpg) repeat; /* alternative for a tile you want to repeat */
 }
 #headercontents {
  width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

and indeed always apply some reset css as stated by others.

Comment: upadted my answer for your background

Comment: I know i sound like a complete amateur at this where does the background-image: (URL); go?

thank you for your help as well :)